# How to get the camera object which is already open in android?

Tags: android, object, camera

How would I get the `android.hardware.Camera` object instance which is already in open state in android?

Answer (score 0):

> how to get the Camera object which is already open in android?

If you opened it within your own application, you must hold onto that `Camera` object (e.g., in your activity). You cannot get it back.

Comment: The camera is already opened with some third partry library, just i want to get that camera object to switch ON/OFF the flash light.

Comment: @sathish: Then call some method on the third-party library to retrieve the `Camera` object.